# Extract value in column to new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-extraction

I want to extract inside of column to several columns. Here is an original data after import to dataframe.

```
data = {'ID':  ['A0001', 'A0002', 'A0003', 'A0004', 'A0005'],
        'Name': ['John', 'Micheal', 'Angle', 'Jim', 'Rome'],
        'Details': ['Type:\nHouse\nVector:\nTriangle\n\nMission:\nCompleted,lv5\n\nNote user:\n#', 'Type:\n#\nVector:\n\n\nMission:\nFailed\nNote user:\n#', 'Type:\nCar\nVector:\nSquare\nMission:\nCompleted\nNote user:\n', 'Type:\n#\nVector:\n#\nMission:\nCompleted without award\n\nNote user:\nNo end', 'Type:\n#\nVector:\n#\nMission:\n\n\nNote user:\nThere are many mistake.\nI cant choose.\nI cant buy.']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Details'])
df

ID      Name    Details
A0001   John    Type:\nHouse\nVector:\nTriangle\n\nMission:\nCompleted,lv5\n\nNote user:\n#
A0002   Micheal Type:\n#\nVector:\n\n\nMission:\nFailed\nNote user:\n#
A0003   Angle   Type:\nCar\nVector:\nSquare\nMission:\nCompleted\nNote user:\n
A0004   Jim     Type:\n#\nVector:\n#\nMission:\nCompleted without award\n\nNote user:\nNo end
A0005   Rome    Type:\n#\nVector:\n#\nMission:\n\n\nNote user:\nThere are many mistake.\nI cant choose.\nI cant buy.
```

I want to extract value in Details column. But I don't know how to do.

My expected data looks like

```
data = {'ID':  ['A0001', 'A0002', 'A0003', 'A0004', 'A0005'],
        'Name': ['John', 'Micheal', 'Angle', 'Jim', 'Rome'],
        'Type': ['House', '#', 'Car', '#', '#'],
        'Vector': ['Triangle', '', 'Square', '#', '#'],
        'Mission': ['Completed,lv5', 'Failed', 'Completed', 'Completed without award', ''],
        'Note user': ['#', '#', '', 'No end', 'There are many mistake.I cant choose.I cant buy.']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Type', 'Vector', 'Mission', 'Note user'])
df



ID      Name    Type    Vector      Mission                      Note
A0001   John    House   Triangle    Completed,lv5                #
A0002   Micheal #                   Failed                       #
A0003   Angle   Car     Square      Completed   
A0004   Jim     #       #           Completed without award      No end
A0005   Rome    #       #                                        There are many mistake.I cant choose.I cant buy.
```

Comment: looks like you want to split the column by `\n` and store all the values into different columns

Comment: similar that but there are some value \n\n\n
the header is word with colon (for example, Type:  Vector:  Mission:   Note:) too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I tried: The first value in `Details` is:

```
'Type:\nHouse\nVector:\nTriangle\n\nMission:\nCompleted,lv5\n\nNote user:\n#'
```

I wrote this function to extract the details into a `dict`. I hardcoded the indices of the array, but you could choose not to do this if you prefer:

```
def extract_details(text):
    array = text.replace("\n\n", "\n").split("\n")
    return {
        array[0].replace(":", ""): array[1],
        array[2].replace(":", ""): array[3],
        array[4].replace(":", ""): array[5],
        array[6].replace(":", ""): array[7]
    }
```

Apply the function to the entire column:

```
df['Details'].apply(extract_details)
```

Concatenate this new column to the original column:

```
pd.concat([
    df,
    pd.DataFrame(df['Details'].apply(extract_details).apply(pd.Series))
], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to get the answers. Link to documentation is attached.

First I am replacing all `\n` with `''`. That way all newline characters are eliminated from `Details` column.

Then I am grabbing all the text in between the two keywords.
For Type, the data is between `'Type:'` and `'Vector:'`. Similarly for Vector and Mission. For Note, I am grabbing all the data after `'Note user:'`. Now that you have extracted the data from `Details` column, you can drop the column.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID':  ['A0001', 'A0002', 'A0003', 'A0004', 'A0005'],
        'Name': ['John', 'Micheal', 'Angle', 'Jim', 'Rome'],
        'Details': ['Type:\nHouse\nVector:\nTriangle\n\nMission:\nCompleted,lv5\n\nNote user:\n#', 'Type:\n#\nVector:\n\n\nMission:\nFailed\nNote user:\n#', 'Type:\nCar\nVector:\nSquare\nMission:\nCompleted\nNote user:\n', 'Type:\n#\nVector:\n#\nMission:\nCompleted without award\n\nNote user:\nNo end', 'Type:\n#\nVector:\n#\nMission:\n\n\nNote user:\nThere are many mistake.\nI cant choose.\nI cant buy.']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Details'])

df['Details'] = df.Details.str.replace('\n','', regex=True)
df['Type']    = df.Details.str.extract('Type\:(.*)Vector')
df['Vector']  = df.Details.str.extract('Vector\:(.*)Mission')
df['Mission'] = df.Details.str.extract('Mission\:(.*)Note')
df['Note']    = df.Details.str.extract('Note user\:(.*)')

print (df[['ID','Name','Type','Vector']])
print (df[['Mission','Note']])
```

The output of this will be:

```
      ID     Name   Type    Vector
0  A0001     John  House  Triangle
1  A0002  Micheal      #          
2  A0003    Angle    Car    Square
3  A0004      Jim      #         #
4  A0005     Rome      #         #

                   Mission                                              Note
0            Completed,lv5                                                 #
1                   Failed                                                 #
2                Completed                                                  
3  Completed without award                                            No end
4                           There are many mistake.I cant choose.I cant buy.
```